# cart challenge javascript logic. is there more than one way to solve?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, logic, this

I just finished the JS intro with code academy, so im kinda new to this.
Please look at the following 2 pieces of code, of a Shopping Cart Challenge.
The first one is the correct code that I found online, in which It scans an array that is already defined and then when inputting a piece of information (in this case "item") an output of another piece of information ("price") is received.

**Here is the "right" solution:**

```js
// Declare Array

var shoppingCart = [];

// Declare function addToCart 

addToCart = function(name,price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  shoppingCart.push(this.name,this.price);
};

function priceCheck(itemName) {
  var i = 0;
  for(i; i <= shoppingCart.length; i++) {
    if(itemName === shoppingCart[i]) {
     console.log(shoppingCart[i += 1]);
     break;
    }
      else {console.log("the searched item is not in the shopping cart");}
  }
}
```

as you can see, this person used .this.

In my code i just added an object (like was instructed). 
Is my logic completely off, or i just need to do some repairs?

**My code:**

```js
shoppingCart = [];

function addToCart(itemName, itemPrice){
 const shiny = {
  name: itemName,
  price: itemPrice
 };
 shoppingCart.push(shiny);
 console.log(shoppingCart);
}

function priceCheck(itemName){
  for(i=0;i<=shoppingCart.length; i++){
    if(itemName===shoppingCart[i]){
      return itemPrice;
    } else{
      console.log('item isnt in cart');
  }}}

addToCart('apple',20);
console.log(shoppingCart);
priceCheck('apple');
```

It works fine until it reaches the priceCheck('apple'); - then it seemes i cannot find 'apple' in the array.

I try to understand if I need to use the (.this) and if I can do it the way I wrote.

PS - sorry if its a mess, its a bit hard for me to explain what im trying to understand :)
PSS - Im not just looking to solve the challenge but really develop a "coding mindset for problems".

THX!

Comment: Where is itemPrice defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shoppingCart[i]` is an object and `name` and `price` are its properties.

You need to access the properties of the object instead.

replace `itemName == shoppingCart[i]` with `itemName == shoppingCart[i].name` and then you can get the price with `shoppingCart[i].price`

```js
shoppingCart = [];

function addToCart(itemName, itemPrice){
 const shiny = {
  name: itemName,
  price: itemPrice
 };
 shoppingCart.push(shiny);
 console.log(shoppingCart);
}

function priceCheck(itemName){
  for(i=0;i<=shoppingCart.length; i++){
    if(itemName===shoppingCart[i].name){//here
      return shoppingCart[i].price;//here
    } else{
      console.log('item isnt in cart');
  }}}

addToCart('apple',20);
console.log(shoppingCart);
console.log(priceCheck('apple'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The "right" solution? Rather not.

```
 addToCart = function(name,price) {
```

This is an *undeclared* and unneccessary function expression. One should rather do:

```
 function addOne(name, price){
```

And accessing `this` here is not really a good practice cause its missleading. I would always only use `this` if you are just refering to OOP code. Additionally the following makes no sense to me:

```
 shoppingCart.push(this.name,this.price);
```

cause that adds the name and the price as different array elements. And this sets variables that are never used (why??):

```
 this.name = name;
 this.price = price;
```

So your solution is actually better than the "right" one IMO. However there are a few things:

```
for(i=0;i<=shoppingCart.length; i++){
```

This iterates until `i` is equal to the length, but as arrays are zero based there is no element at that position. Do:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++)
```

Additionally, objects are compared by reference, but you actually want to compare them by value. E.g. you could take the name property:

```
  if(name === shoppingCart[i].name)
```

And a small style tip, dont do this:

```
}}}
```

---

How i would do that:

```
  const cart = [];

  function addToCart(name, price){
    cart.push({name, price});
  }

  function priceOf(findName){
    for(const {name, price} of cart)
       if(findName === name) return price;
    return NaN;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An obvious issue is here:

```
if(itemName===shoppingCart[i]){
```

You're comparing itemName to the object containing name and price instead of the name.

I don't remember the exact JS syntax for this but it should be something like

```
if (itemName === shoppingCart[i].name) {
```